# How to use a pdf.js promise in an own class?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, pdf.js

I like to write a custom PDF Viewer based on pdf.js in es6.
I have a viewer Class which calls a PdfLoader Class to get a pagebuffer filled with canvases but I'm stuck with the promises:

The PdfLoader Class:

```
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist");
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "./pdf.worker.bundle.js";

export default class PdfLoader{

    constructor(pdfPath, owner){
        this.pdfPath = pdfPath;
        this.customPdfViewer = owner;
    }

    loadingTask;

    getPageAsCanvas(pageNum){

        this.loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.pdfPath);
        this.loadingTask.promise
            .then(function (pdfDocument) {
                if(pdfDocument.numPages >= pageNum){
                    
                    return pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum).then(function (pdfPage) {
                        
                        const viewport = pdfPage.getViewport({ scale: 1.0 });

                        // There will be more canvases, this is just prototype stuff
                        const canvas = document.getElementById("pdfCanvas");
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        const renderTask = pdfPage.render({
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport,
                        });

                        return renderTask.promise.then(function(){
                            this.customPdfViewer.insertPageToBuffer(pageNum, canvas);
                        })
                    })
                }
                console.log('Page ' + pageNum + ' does not exist!');
            })
            .catch(function (reason) {
                console.error("Error: " + reason);
            });
    }
}
```

And the CustomPdfViewer:

```
import PdfLoader from "./PdfLoader";

export default class CustomPdfViewer{

    constructor(pdfPath = "./assets/pdf/test.pdf", pageBufferSize = 4) {
        this.pdfLoader = new PdfLoader(pdfPath, this);
        this.pageBufferSize = pageBufferSize;
        this.pagesBuffer = new Array(pageBufferSize).fill({});
    }

    init() {

        for(let i = 1; i <= this.pageBufferSize; i++){
            this.pdfLoader.getPageAsCanvas(i);
        }
    }

    insertPageToBuffer(pageNum, canvas){
        this.pagesBuffer[pageNum - 1] = canvas;
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

In my main script I just call

```
// Document Ready stuff and imports...

var pdfViewer = new CustomPdfViewer("./assets/pdf/test2.pdf");
    pdfViewer.init();

// ...
```

This even works so far but everytime (even if my pagebuffer is only 1) I get the message:

*Error: TypeError: this is undefined*

This comes from the catch part of my promise. It seems that my then and my catch part will be executed after each other in a single call.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I finally figured out a solution, by using arrow functions.
Something like this, brings the "this" back into the right context:

Before:
`return pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum).then(function (pdfPage) {`

After:
`pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum).then((pdfPage) => {`